# IRC messages randomly not sending from bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, bots, irc

I wrote a very simple bot in Python to received a webhook, parse the data, then send messages to IRC. Everything works as expected except at completely random times messages will fail to send. I don't get any error messages from the IRC server, but they simply won't show up in IRC. I construct an array of messages to send, then loop through them to send. I authenticate to IRC via SASL. I confirmed that all messages are in the list that are supposed to be sent. Sometimes they all send fine, sometimes only some send, and sometimes none of them send.  I try to get messages back from the server but there appears to be none.

When I print the messages array it looks like:

```
['[\x0313repo\x0f] \x0315user-name\x0f force pushed \x021\x0f commit(s) to \x036master\x0f: \x032\x1fhttps://github.com/owner/repo/compare/e1a06c001733...387b204c4303\x0f\r\n', '\x0313repo\x0f/\x036master\x0f \x0314387b204\x0f \x0315user-name\x0f: commit message here\r\n']
```

My send command specifically:

```
self.irc.send(bytes("PRIVMSG {} :{}\r\n".format(channel, message), "UTF-8"))
```

Full Code:

```
import base64
import json
import re
import socket
import ssl
from time import sleep


class IRC(object):

    def __init__(self, sslConfig):
        if sslConfig is True:
            self.irc = ssl.wrap_socket(
                socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM),
                ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
            )
        else:
            self.irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def getText(self):
        text=self.irc.recv(2040)
        return text.decode("UTF-8")

    def waitAndSee(self, search):
        tries = 0
        while True:
            text = self.getText()
            if tries > 20:
                raise ConnectionError("Unable to connect to IRC: %s" % text) 
            ack = re.search(search, text, re.MULTILINE)
            if ack:
                return
            sleep(0.25)
            tries += 1

    def authenticate(self, nick, password):
        self.irc.send(bytes("CAP REQ :sasl\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        self.waitAndSee(r'(.*)CAP(.*)ACK(.*)')
        self.irc.send(bytes("AUTHENTICATE PLAIN\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        self.waitAndSee(r'(.*)AUTHENTICATE \+(.*)')
        auth = (
            "{nick}\0{nick}\0{password}"
        ).format(
            nick=nick,
            password=password
        )
        auth = base64.encodestring(auth.encode("UTF-8"))
        auth = auth.decode("UTF-8").rstrip("\n")
        self.irc.send(bytes("AUTHENTICATE "+auth+"\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        self.waitAndSee(r'(.*)903(.*):SASL authentication successful(.*)')
        self.irc.send(bytes("CAP END\r\n", "UTF-8"))

    def sendMessage(self, channel, message):
        self.irc.send(bytes("PRIVMSG {} :{}\r\n".format(channel, message), "UTF-8"))

    def sendPong(self, text):
        self.irc.send(bytes(text.replace('PING', 'PONG'), "UTF-8"))

    def connect(self, host, port, channels, nick, password):
        print("Connecting to {}:{} with nick {} and channels: {}".format(host, port, nick, ','.join(channels)))
        self.irc.connect((host, port))
        if password != None:
            self.authenticate(nick, password)                                             
        self.irc.send(bytes("USER {nick} {nick} {nick} {nick}\r\n".format(nick=nick), "UTF-8"))
        self.irc.send(bytes("NICK {}\r\n".format(nick), "UTF-8"))
        for channel in channels:          
            self.irc.send(bytes("JOIN {}\r\n".format(channel), "UTF-8"))

    def disconnect(self, channels):
        for channel in channels:               
            self.irc.send(bytes("PART {}\r\n".format(channel), "UTF-8"))
        self.irc.send(bytes("QUIT\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        self.irc.close()



try:
    irc = IRC(pool.ssl)
    irc.connect(pool.host, pool.port, pool.channels, pool.nick, pool.password)

    # Wait until connection is established
    while True:    
        text = irc.getText()
        if re.search(r'(.*)End of /NAMES list.(.*)', text, re.MULTILINE):
            break
        elif re.search(r'(.*)PING(.*)', text, re.MULTILINE):
            irc.sendPong(text)
        elif re.search(r'(.*)433(.*)Nickname is already in use(.*)', text, re.MULTILINE):
            raise ConnectionError("Nickname is already in use")
        elif re.search(r'(.*)ERROR :(.*)', text, re.MULTILINE):
            raise ConnectionError(text)
        sleep(0.25)
    for channel in pool.channels:
        for message in messages:
            irc.sendMessage(channel, message)

    irc.disconnect(pool.channels)

    return 'success'

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return 'error'
```

---

**EDIT**

As I'm researching this, it seems like the contents of the message are the problem. In the example array, the first message has two colons. That's the message that usually doesn't work. If I do `message.replace(":","")` it seems to send fine. But I have another message that has two colons that seems to work fine, so not sure if that's a red herring.

**EDIT 2**

Message contents were definitely a red herring. See solution below.

Comment: FWIW, I've only tried sending messages to freenode, but that's probably the only IRC i'll be sending to.

Comment: I also think every time a message doesn't show up it's the first one in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Changing `if re.search(r'(.*)End of /NAMES list.(.*)', text, re.MULTILINE)` to `if re.search(r'(.*)00[1-4] '+pool.nick+'(.*)', text, re.MULTILINE)` fixed the issue. This send messages sooner after connecting.

See description below.

---

After lots of testing I found the issue, and it's not what I expected. The problem, is this line: `if re.search(r'(.*)End of /NAMES list.(.*)', text, re.MULTILINE):` in the `while True:` loop.

After I connected to IRC and Joined a channel, I loop through the messages returned from IRC to ensure I'm successfully connected before sending message. Well the message that contains "End of /NAMES list." is one of the last messages sent from the IRC server. (after MOTD and all that). Sometimes this was taking too long and it's like my connection goes idle or something. Then sending a message woke up the connection, but didn't actually send the message. This is why it would happen at random. Sometimes receiving the message would be fast and sometimes it would be slow (probably based on the load of the IRC server).

So I switched the line I'm searching for to `if re.search(r'(.*)00[1-4] '+pool.nick+'(.*)', text, re.MULTILINE)` instead because that's one of the first messages sent after successful connection to IRC. This happens before MOTD and all that stuff, but still means I'm connected. Now when I send my message right after I connect they all go through consistently.